# Accessing data context in rendered callback

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

I understand that you need to use this.data to access the data context. However that only works if you wrap the template with {{#with}} or the other wrappers.  What if you have access to this data in the template through something like iron router. Now whenever that template is rendered I need access to that data. How should I do that?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what the question is.  Are you saying you're setting the data context in iron-router using the `data` option and you then want to access this data in a `Template.rendered` callback?  If so, it's just `this.data`, at least for anything below 0.8.0.

Comment: This is for meteor 0.8.0 this.data is undefined.

Comment: It seems that there is required to pass data to a dynamic template, yeah? For example, with Meteor 0.7 we could use `{{>tmpl context}}` and the context would be passed to `tmpl`. But with meteor0.8 this doesn't work any more

Comment: so, is that possible to access data context in `rendered` callback in Meteor 0.9 ?

Comment: You can use {{> UI.dynamic}} now

Answer (score 1):

I'm running Meteor 0.9 and `this.data.yourDataObjectName` works fine.